# How to make user specific forms?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

So I want to make it so a "Tutor" can select a "Student", now each tutor has a different set of Students so the drop down list needs to be unique.

So this is the part of forms where question comes from, tutor1 get's passed through by response into views, then from views it needs to be passed into the form so Students.objects.all displays all of the students that tutor1 has. (The query set part is fine and I believe the Field is also correct) the part that doesn't work is passing in response or passing in the tutor1 into the form and so far I can't find anywhere how to do this.

```
student = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Students.objects.all(tutor=tutor1.id))
```

This is the last piece of the hard part of my website so I'd be so grateful if anyone knows how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind think I found an answer, you can't haha. But the strategy instead is using class based views.

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/django-how-to-pass-the-user-object-into-form-classes-ee322f02948c

This page explains it really well.